# Is there such a thing as a minor blues scale?

Tags: blues

I have learned the **Blues** scale as 1, b3, 4, b5, 5, b7.

I'm looking at a chart "Stolen Moments" (in the RealBook) and it says to solo on C Minor Blues.

Is the `minor blues` the same as the **Blues** as I've described above?
So the notes would be:
C, Eb, F, Gb, G, Bb, C

Or is there a minor version of this scale?

Comment: That's the common minor blues scale. For reference, the major blues would be 1, 2, b3, 3, 5, 6.

Comment: That IS the minor version!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Officially, yes. It gets credence as it features in some music exams. Cm blues scale contains the notes C E♭ F G♭ G and B♭

That ♭5 is better known in jazz circles as ♯4, but for all intents and purposes it sounds like the same note.

I think the problem arises because the Blues often gets to be played with other notes - notably those of the major Blues scale. And, of course, several micro notes which appear mainly on guitar or sax that cannot be defined using 12tet.

So, to pigeon-hole it, we can say it contains only the notes first quoted.

Comment: Doesn't #4 make more sense functionally?

Comment: @MCMastery - not particularly. There's a b3, b5 and b7. Although jazzers seem to prefer #4.

Comment: In a run up the scale, I'd much prefer it notated as F♯ rather than G♭ to avoid writing G♮ for the 5th degree. Depends on context, obviously.

Comment: @user45266 - 99% of the time, that note is played in real music, rather than as part of a scale. It's only the academic side that somehow needs to pigeon-hole it. More often than not, when I play the note, I don't even give it a consideration as far as what it might be called! And if it's blues or jazz, I feel the players will think likewise.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the term "Blues Scale" is used in more than one context.

Some sources quote the "Blues scale" as the Major pentatonic with a b3 added while other simply equate Blues with the scale you have given above, minor pentatonic with a #4.

In the context you have provided I think the scale you have described is the minor Blues scale.

Answer (score 1):

When musicians talk about the "blues scale", they could mean either the major blues scale or the minor blues scale. Starting on C, C D D♯(E♭) E G A is the major blues scale, and C E♭ F F♯(G♭) G B♭ is the minor blues scale. Note that both are modifications of their respective pentatonic scales, with one note added in.

As for why the minor blues scale sometimes gets called "*the* blues scale", that's probably because it can be played over both major and minor blues songs, whereas playing the major blues scale over a minor blues song sounds unidiomatic to the blues genre.

Comment: I wish I could mark two answers as correct, as I also like this answer.  Thank you!